# Issues by the redefinition of a macro in C

Tags: c

I want to change the  value of a macro during the run of the program, for that I've wrote this example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX  (65535 *0.5)

int main ( ){
float amp = 0.0;
float temp = 0.0 ;
temp    = MAX ;
char c;

while (1){
  printf(" MAX value %.2d.%.3d \n ", (short)temp,(short)(temp*1000));
  scanf("%c",&c);
  if( c =='x') {
    #undef MAX
    #define MAX  (65535 +amp);
    amp+= 0.1;
    temp = MAX;
  }
}
return 0 ; }
```

I've got two problems : 
1. the printf doessn't show the values as hoped, for instand 19.211, it always
 `-32768.-32768` 
2. I don't see any change  of the value of the macro.

any idea what I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: Did you expect the value of the macro to change when you enter `'x'`?

Comment: acutaly yes I'Ve read this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274500/redefining-or-changing-macro-value and was hopping it wil do it

Comment: Macros aren't variables. They are macros. If you need a variable, use a variable instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only define macros at compile time. The [c preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) replaces every occurrance of a macro before actual compilation happens, with **gcc** you can see what code was generated after preprocessing by using the `-E` switch, if you try it experimenting with different macros, you may get to understand the preprocessor a little better, read the link to understand more.

This

```
if( c =='x') {
  #undef MAX
  #define MAX  (65535 +amp);
  amp+= 0.1;
  temp = MAX;
}
```

does not do what you think.

If you execute the preprocessor on the source code, then what will actually happen is that the snippet above will be compiled as

```
if( c =='x') {
  amp+= 0.1;
  temp = MAX;
}
```

so as you can see, it doesn't do what you think.

Also, this is not related to the macro redefinition issue, but your code has a bug that can make it enter an infinite loop, this

```
scanf("%c",&c);
```

will keep scanning the `'\n'` that is left in the `stdin` after pressing <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd>, so you need to explicitly ignore that character by adding a white space before the specifier like this

```
scanf(" %c", &c);
/*     ^ white space goes here */
```

**Note**: another answer has suggested that you are using the incorrect data type and suggested a solution, you should [take a look at it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29257162/1983495), since in fact it seems your program has an integer overflow issue.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are resolved during compilation, so during program execution there is no such thing like `MAX` - each occurence was already replaced by its value (`65535`).

However, if you need to define local constant (local in terms of translation unit), why not use static variable?

```
static unsigned int MAX = 65535;
```

And then:

```
if (c == 'x')
{
    MAX = 65535 + amp;
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's run your file through the C preprocessor (CPP) manually. The result is

```
int main ( ) {
    float amp = 0.0;
    float temp = 0.0 ;
    temp = (65535 *0.5) ;
    char c;

    while (1) {
        printf(" MAX value %.2d.%.3d \n ", (short)temp,(short)(temp*1000));
        scanf("%c",&c);
        if( c =='x') {


            amp+= 0.1;
            temp = (65535 +amp);;
        }
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Macros are evaluated before the compiler even sees your source code. You  cannot change the value of a macro based on a decision taken at runtime.

Why not instead use a variable `float max = ...` and change that one's value depending on user input?

Answer (score 1):

You are using too short data type and printing the fractional part incorrectly. Consider doing this:

```
double i;
printf(" MAX value %.2d.%.3d \n ", (int)temp,(int)(modf(temp,&i)*1000));
```

...instead of this:

```
printf(" MAX value %.2d.%.3d \n ", (short)temp,(short)(temp*1000));
```

Be sure to `#include <math.h>` if using `modf`.

Your redefinition of the `MAX` macro looks strange to me, though. Macros are defined at compile time, not at run time, so most of the time you don't want to redefine macros.

Note also that

```
scanf("%c",&c);
```

will read the newline as a separate character, so you want to do instead:

```
scanf(" %c",&c);
```

...to consume whitespace. Do consider checking also for the `EOF` (end-of-file) condition; currently you don't do that.